# Beanstalk php blue-green deployment is returning a 503

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm doing a blue-green deployment to migrate my wordpress application to a new php version (from 7.0 to 7.3). Somehow after launching the new beanstalk environment the application returns a 503.

Error_log contains the following:

```
[pid 3502] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: 
FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
[Thu Mar 26 10:55:01.252011 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] 
[pid 3502] [client 127.0.0.1:36944] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

Anyone knows how to fix this issue? My Wordpress environment isn't using fcgi as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my instances were still running php 7.0 instead of 7.3. The project had a ebextensions configuration file that installed a php70 package. This made it so the environment was using php 7.0 instead of that what was specified in the console.

So check your ebextensions config files.